# What means *p++=x

Tags: c

I'm new in C and I'm wondering what `*p++=x` means.
I understand what `var += x` means, what `*var++` means but I don't get this one.

Comment: The fact that you have to work so hard to parse this is why you would be better writing it out in two distinct instructions.

Answer (score 10):

It means assign `x` to `*p` and then make `p` point to the next element:

```
*p = x;
p++;
```

Comment: Now you say it, it seems obvious ... Thanks ! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators, so `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)`; that is, you are dereferencing the result of the expression `p++`.

So the expression `*p++ = x` assigns the value of `x` to whatever `p` is pointing to and advances `p` to point to the next element.